# Pytest does not see files in folders in Django

Tags: django, pytest

I have a following question:

I have a test function written in Pytest for Django project:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_class():
    path = Path(r'ascertain\tests\csv')
    handler = DatabaseCSVUpload(path, delimiter=',')
    handler()

ascertain\tests\test_upload_csv.py:19 (TestUploadCSVtoDatabaseNegative.test_class)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hardcase1\PycharmProjects\telephone_numbers\ascertain\tests\test_upload_csv.py", line 27, in test_class
    handler()
  File "C:\Users\hardcase1\PycharmProjects\telephone_numbers\ascertain\handle_csv.py", line 129, in __call__
    for file in self.get_csv_files():
  File "C:\Users\hardcase1\PycharmProjects\telephone_numbers\ascertain\handle_csv.py", line 48, in get_csv_files
    raise EmptyFolder()
telephone_numbers.custom_exceptions.EmptyFolder:
```

It basically expects  *.csv files be inside directory  ‘path’ and handle them to upload to DB.

Problem is that Pytest can’t see any files in this directory as well as in other directories. I have tried multiple times with different folders.

In fact file is there:

```
list(Path(r'ascertain\tests\csv').glob('*.csv'))
[WindowsPath('ascertain/tests/csv/test.csv')]
```

Same test function written in unitests works correctly:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class TestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_open(self):
        path = Path(r'ascertain\tests\csv')
        handler = DatabaseCSVUpload(path, delimiter=',')
        handler()

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).


Destroying test database for alias 'default'...


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Question is -what I need to do to make Pytest see this file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this problem relates to Pytest vs Unittest, rather I think it has to do with where you executing these files from. I think you can resolve this by using an absolute path instead of the relative path you included in the example.

An absolute path will start at your systems root directory instead of starting at the directory you are executing the file from. I'm not a Windows user, but from what I can see online the path to this data should look something like this `C:/users/path/to/data`.

Comment: What happens when you add a print statement with the current directory path? If you print these two statements, `pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()` and `pathlib.Path().absolute()` do you get the same result with Unittest and Pytest?

Comment: @ yes, same path. It sees folders with files, but just sees them empty. Thats the thing